Jupyter Notebook in VSCode. Customisation of markdown
I’m trying to customise the style of markdown in Jupyter notebook within VSCode, using a custom.css file but, for some reason, it doesn’t work.
This is the css file:
h1 {
    color: #00252b;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

h2 {
    color: indianred;
    font-size: 2.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

h3 {
    color: #005287;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

h4 {
    color: #00A86B;
    font-size: 2.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

h5 {
    color: #ffb66f;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

h6 {
    color: maroon;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

I tried to add the custom folder and custom.css file in Jupyter directory as described in the Jupyter documentation but nothing happens (/Users/user_name/.jupyter/custom/custom.css).
I also tried with the “custom css and JS loader” extension provided in VSCode but it affects the html style  of vscode but it doesn’t change the markdown style in Jupyter notebook. I read that this function was not yet supported in 2021, someone knows if something is changed since then?
Whatever suggestion is highly appreciated.

"I read that this function was not yet supported in 2021". Maybe that was here & at linked reference? (you may be limited in links as a new user?) Why do you think things may have changed and/or why not use https://github.com/drcika/apc-extension#apciframestyle ? I'm also not following why you mention trying Jupyter's documented way, which is here, if you aren't using Jupyter? Did jupyter --paths work inside VSCode and match so it seemed viable?

Hi! Thank you for the answer. I use Jupyter notebook inside vscode. The problem is that the customisation of the css file works only if I use Jupyter through terminal while it doesn’t work if I use it in VSCode. I will have a look in the extension that you mentioned, I did know it. Bay and thanks again!

"I use Jupyter notebook inside vscode." That isn't exactly true. I think you are using an extension in VSCode that provides basic support for Jupyter Notebook file use, see here. That isn't straight Jupyter and so solutions in the documentation  for Jupyter Notebook (which is a separate project than what you are using to edit  & work with Jupyter Notebook .ipynb files) aren't necessarily going to work as written.

Thank you for your support. I just installed the extension that you suggested me and finally I have my own headers in the extension that "simulates jupyter notebook". Top! Thank you so much, I had been trying to do that for days!

Please, then write up your answer and mark it answered. Or update your post at the end with what others should do. I'm not quite following what fixed what here.
